# Pardot and Marketing Cloud Sends running in parralel

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, pardot

We have a use case where we will be using Pardot and Marketing Cloud for email sends simultaneously while we transition off Pardot. Since Subscribers/Contacts can exist in both systems, I would like to know how to manage unsubscribes.

More specifically, the contact is sent an email from Pardot and unsubscribes from the Preference Center in Pardot but how does Marketing Cloud know not to send that same user an email ? and vice versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

when a contact/subscriber is unsubscribed from the preference center the email opt out field will be checked in the salesforce, we can run a automation for every 15 mins(this is the min time) with sql query with journey attached to it where the synchronized data extension will pull the updated data from the salesforce.

Comment: Thanks @yaseanth.r, can you tell me more in detail how Pardot will get the result of the unsubscribe

Comment: Hi Paul, there is no connector available in market for pardot and marketing cloud integration. All we need to do is sync marketing cloud and pardot to salesforce . otherwise it wont be possible to do such thing in parallel... there is tool which is under development to integrate marketing cloud and pardot .. here  is the link https://automate.io/integration/pardot/salesforce-marketing-cloud